# Some upvotes don't increase my reputation - is it a bug?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Here is a screenshot of my reputation for today:

[image]

There are 3 upvotes, which didn't gain reputation. If you sum the numbers on the left they indeed sum up to 245. Also I was online when the second upvote was cast and my overal reputation didn't increase - I am sure about that. In other words - it's not just a UI issue.

Is it a bug, or I am missing something?

**EDIT:**
Also, for the 4th upvote for [Class methods vs instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545853/class-methods-vs-instance-methods/6545912#6545912), I actually have 3 upvotes, but it still only shows +20.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You hit the reputation cap. As explained in [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> - A maximum of +200 reputation may be gained per day. Accepted answers are immune to this cap ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/)) as are bounties ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483019/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow)).  (A new day starts 0:00 UTC == 7pm EST == 4pm PST == 1am CET == 5:30 am IST.)

You have 3 accepted answers, at +15 each, so you got `245 - 3(15) = 200` reputation from upvotes. Any upvotes after that won't give you more rep

---

**Edit**: This got a little long for the comments; this is (I believe) the reason a post higher in the list got rep while ones lower did not:

The top of the list is (I numbered the posts for ease of reference):

```
(1) +15  15 mins ago    accept  Complex Regex problem with hyperlink not matching “?”
(2)      33 mins ago    upvote  Complex Regex problem with hyperlink not matching “?”
(3) +15  6 hours ago    accept  Empty elements in C# byte array
(4) +20  6 hours ago    upvote  Class methods vs instance methods
(5)      6 hours ago    upvote  How to select a field with linq on datarow
(6)      6 hours ago    upvote  wildcard generics in HashSet constructor
(7) +110 7 hours ago    upvote  Empty elements in C# byte array
```

He got 11 upvotes on (7). Then he got 2 upvotes on (4), which got him to the rep cap. Then he got an upvote on (6), and an upvote on (5), which didn't get him any rep. Then he got another upvote on (4), which also wasn't worth any rep, but put it above (5) and (6) on the list, as the list appears to sort by most recent upvote. Then (3) got accepted, which did get him +15, because accepts are immune to the cap. (2) got upvoted, which got him nothing, and then accepted, which gives him the +15 at (1)

There's a text-based version of the reputation summary at [`/reputation`](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), which breaks down each vote into its own line and sorts them in the order they happened, so looking at that might be simpler for cases like this

Answer (score 3):

You hit the 200 rep cap for the day, which does not include bounty awards, the 15 for one of your answers being accepted, or the 2 for you accepting an answer on one of your questions.